# How to open shared folder in Windows XP from nautilus

Tags: 12.04, samba, windows-xp, shared-folders

I have fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04, and want to connect with Windows Network.
Actually I want to open some shared Folder in another PC (Windows XP).

I'm just need to open this Window's folder use nautilus not in terminal.
After install `smbfs`, i don't know how to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is :

1. sudo apt-get install smbfs
2. cd /etc/samba
3. sudo nano  smb.conf
4. Edit "workgroup = windows workgroup name"
5. sudo service smbd restart
6. open Home Folder/Browse Network/Windows Network/network group name
7. choose PC name
8. Fill username and password

this is the simple way, if you couldn't work with `Connect to server..`, espesially if you don't have information about the server name. About no need to use samba, I will try first.

---

EDIT

I try to `sudo apt-get purge smbfs`, it means I don't have `samba` anymore. So, for 12.04 (I don't know for the previous ubuntu version) we can directly open shared windows folder from another PC.

Comment: no need for installing samba to access the network. In ubuntu 12.04 you can also share a folder without installing samba.

Answer (score 3):

In Nautilus you should be able to select "Connect to Server.." from the File menu.

This will give you a dialogue to fill in.

First set the type to "Windows Share" then fill in the information for the server you want to connect to.

Once connected you can then bookmark the directories that you are interested in for easier connection later.

Comment: i have tried that, but doesn't work for me,